# accessing a 'media:thumbnail' tag in rss feed using basic javascript xml

Tags: javascript, xml, mediarss

How would I access a mediarss tag like `<media:thumbnail>` using basic javascript like `getElementsByTagName`? P.S I do not want to use a library or server side scripting, also a json object is not available from the rss feed i am using, and i do not want to create one in php...

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is covered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/vf-eIAZ3e4s), where they talk about using `getElementsByTagNameNS`.